# MonoTouch.Dialog: Setting Image of StyledStringElement in Background

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

My app calculates the Image of the StyledStringElement and this process takes a good amount of time. It's all done locally.

How can I do something like this pseudo code:

```
myElement.Image = PlaceHolderImage; 
myElement.GoGetTheImageFromSomeLongRunningTask = GetImageFromSomeFuntionThatWillTakeTime();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like this (not tested):

```
myElement.Image = PlaceHolderImage;
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem ((v) =>
{
    var image = GetImageFromSomeFunctionThatWillTakeTime ();
    BeginInvokeOnMainThread (() =>
    {
        myElement.Image = image;
        myRoot.ReloadData ();
    });
});
```

Note that this assumes that GetImageFromSomeFunctionThatWillTakeTime can actually be executed on a secondary thread. You can easily test this by using the current MonoTouch beta (5.3.2), since you'll get an exception if you do something that's not allowed on a secondary thread.